# Custom listAdapter for listFragment

Tags: android

Hey i made a custom Adapter for my listFragment but here:

CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,items);
I dont what to put here and especially fo the this maybe i need to put a getActivity()

```
 public class BlankFragment extends ListFragment {
    ListView lv;
    View rootview;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        final String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heroes);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);





        return rootview;

    }
```

The custom adapter

```
 public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Integer> mModel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Context mContext;
    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mModel.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        return mModel.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
            parent) {
        CustomListViewView v = null;
// Notre vue n'a pas encore été construite, nous le faisons
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = new CustomListViewView(mContext);
        } // Notre vue peut être récupérée, nous le faisons
        else {
            v = (CustomListViewView) convertView;
        }
        v.bind(getItem(position));
        return v;
    }
    public void bind(List<Integer> model) {
        mModel = model;
    }
}
```

the layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to show us the constructors for `CustomListViewAdapter` for us to be able to give a definitive answer.

You probably need to get the activity. For that, replace `this` with `this.getActivity()`.

EDIT:

Well, your constructor looks like this:

```
public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

So the only thing thing you'd need to pass in is `this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I added the layout and the custom adapter

Comment: You mean like this: CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),items);

Comment: @BtAndro you need to review the basics of Java before you get into all of this. Your constructor takes JUST the context, so give it JUST the context. Without the items...